# CAAnimation Delegate not called Custom Loading Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, loading

I'm trying to create a custom loading animation. The animation consists of two parts. First, 5 lines are drawn (animated) outwards. When the lines are finished drawing, they are faded away and the cycle is started over. In order to get this sequential behavior with two animations, I am using two `CABasicAnimations`, both of which have the same delegate. In the delegate method `animationDidStop:`, I dispatch to the correct animation (animation 2 if animation 1 just finished, and vise versa). Here is the relevant code:

```
-(void)startAnimating{//this method launches the line growing animation
    self.hidden = NO;
    BOOL delegateSet = NO;

    animationPhase = 1;

    for(CAShapeLayer * pathLayer in _lines){
        [pathLayer removeAllAnimations];
        pathLayer.strokeColor = _strokeColor.CGColor;
        CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        pathAnimation.duration = .95;
        pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
        if(!delegateSet){//just set one delegate
            pathAnimation.delegate = self;
            delegateSet = YES;
        }
        [pathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
    }
}



//this delegate method dispatches the next animation
- (void) animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{    
    if(animationPhase == 1)[self fadeLines];
    else if(animationPhase == 2)[self startAnimating];
}

-(void)fadeLines{//this method launches the fading animation
    self.hidden = NO;
    BOOL delegateSet = NO;

    animationPhase = 2;

    for(CAShapeLayer * pathLayer in _lines){
        [pathLayer removeAllAnimations];
        CABasicAnimation *strokeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeColor"];
        strokeAnim.fromValue         = (id) pathLayer.strokeColor;
        strokeAnim.toValue           = (id) [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        strokeAnim.duration          = .2;
        if(!delegateSet){//just set one delegate
            strokeAnim.delegate = self;
            delegateSet = YES;
        }
        [pathLayer addAnimation:strokeAnim forKey:@"animateStrokeColor"];
        pathLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    }


}
```

So this all works great when it's run on it's own (not while other things are being done in the background). But when I use it as a loading animation (while other things are being done in the background), the first initial grow animation is performed, but `animationDidStop:` is never called.

I've tried using transactions with completion blocks instead of using the delegate pattern, but I get the same issue. I can't use `CAAnimationGroup` with appropriate beginTimes because I need the animations to loop.

Another thing to note is if I just perform the growing animation with a high repeat count, everything works fine. The only issue is the sequential looping of the two animations. If anyone knows how I can fix this, or knows a different way to sequentially loop two CAAnimations, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Your code looks reasonable, if a little confusing. What do you mean about other things being done in the background? Are they being run on a separate thread, or network calls that are performed asynchronously? Or do you have a long-running routine that is running on the main thread?

Comment: @DuncanC the background behavior is the fetching of data from a local database which is done on a separate thread, then the populating of custom UIViews based on the data from the database which is necessarily done on the main thread. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Your code should work, and if it works correctly EXCEPT when you are doing your background loading, my gut is there is something wonky in the way you are doing your background processing. Have you double and triple-checked your background code to make sure you're not doing any UI updates from the background? It's fairly easy to miss something that has a drawing side-effect, and the effects can be bizarre and unpredictable. You might want to post your background code, or at least the setup and teardown, as an edit to your question.

Comment: @DuncanC I don't believe that I am doing any UI updates on a background thread. There is too much going on to post here. I will get out my fine tooth comb and check for myself.

Comment: __Be aware that `CAAnimation`'s `delegate` is strong, so you might need to set it to `nil` to avoid retain cycles!__